# localhost/xampp - This webpage is not available

Tags: php, mysql, apache

[screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9X9x.png)

Before then it was working but heres what happened....

what i did LOG 
 
Before the problem... 
 
1. installed Wampserver 
 
2. run it and click server online so yeah its online then offline it.. 
 
3. goto my Xampp control panel 
 
4. says in log: Problem detected! 
 
   wamp server is using the port 80! blah blah... 
5. gone to localhost/xampp 
 
6. says Webpage not available shows a wamp logo on title(look in screenshot). 
 
7. *Realised that its a error and bad move.... 
 
8. uninstalls wamp and all its components in one click... BAM! 
 
9. restarts pc... 
 
10. goes to localhost/wamp 
 
11. webpage not available... wtf

so yeah thats how the problem occured... how to fix it?

Comment: Basically.. i expected a xampp logo and expected it to work and just wanted to know how to stop wamp server and make it change into a xampp logo when i goto localhost/xampp

Answer (score 0):

You go to `"Control Panel" >> "System And Security" >> "Administrative Tools" >> "Component Services" >> "Services (LOCAL)"`

Now, since you are using WAMP and not IIS you should disable the `"World Wide Web Publishing Service"` and the `"Web Deployment Agent Service"`. You are good to go.

If this doesn't work you probably have Skype using Port 80 (if you actually have Skype). (If you have IIS installed you should also disable it. But if you don't have it installed you shouldn't worry!)

Comment: Well since my wamp is already uninstalled. i could not find the web deployment and world wide publishing stuff on my service local.. do i have to reinstall it or is it the IIS? and how do i disable it? pls specify

Comment: how you are trying to run localserver if you have uninstalled wampserver ??

Comment: I have no idea. i just goto localhost/xampp and still shows the wamp logo.. i deleted every wamp data n files.. btw when i first installed Xampp with apache working. the localhost still does not work either way...